# What is the correct way to instantiate object on CorDapp start and use it further in Corda flows?

Tags: corda

I need to initiate and object inside CorDapp when it starts and later use it in different flows.

I probably can create a singleton and use 'static' companion method to get this object instantiating it on first call. But maybe there is way more correct from Corda architecture point of view? Something more enterprisy like DI? Or at least onCreate()/onStart() method where I can do all heavy work to don't make first customer wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a singleton object in a *CorDapp* per se. Each node is a standalone Java process, and they cannot share objects between one another. You'll therefore have to follow one of the following patterns:

- Your CorDapp defines a singleton object, and you install it on several nodes. Each node has their own singleton object
- Your CorDapp defines a singleton object, and you only install it on one node. When other nodes want to access the functionality or data of the singleton object, they do this by using flows to send data back and forth with the node that holds the singleton object

Singleton objects in nodes are known as *services*. You create a service by defining a class in your CorDapp that:

- Takes a single constructor parameter of type `ServiceHub`
- Has the `@CordaService` annotation
- Extends the `SingletonSerializeAsToken` class

For example:

```
@CordaService
class MyService(val services: ServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken() {

    val myData = "someData"

    fun myFunctionality(int: Int): String {
        ...
    }
}
```

For an example, take a look at the Oracle Example [here](https://github.com/corda/samples). If you explore this sample, you'll see that it defines a service that is only installed on one node, the oracle. Other nodes query the service using flows to extract its data.

To get a reference to the service (i.e. singleton object) in a flow, you use the following syntax:

```
serviceHub.cordaService(MyService::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like what I need. One more follow-up question - do you know when service object will be instantiated - on node(cordapp) startup or lazy-style during first call to it?

Comment: They are currently started automatically when the node starts up.